# refrencing the layout crashes the application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-3.0

i am a newbie in development and this language, i wanted to make a bottom navigation bar. I made the xml file for menu, but when i referenced that file in the other xml file, which is basically a toolbar, the application crashed everytime.

here are the lines of codes

```
<RelativeLayout

   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="50dp">


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavViewbar"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nevigation_menu"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

it appeasers normal in preview,but when i run the application, it crashes.
and when i remove the line of code
 app:menu="@menu/bottom_nevigation_menu"
and run the app, the toolbar appears and the app runs properly.
I am unable to find the solution

bottom_nevigation_menu.xml file is

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/ic-house"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping"
    android:title="">

</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic-search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="">

</item>


<item
    android:id="@+id/house"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_world"
    android:title="">

</item>


<item
    android:id="@+id/ic-android"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
    android:title="">

</item>
```

Comment: share your `/bottom_nevigation_menu`

Comment: This is almost certainly due to a problem with your layout files.

Comment: in which package your menu.xml is located?

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your menu items in a  tag.

```
<menu>

<item
android:id="@+id/ic-house"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping"
android:title=""/>
...
...
</menu>
```

Comment: they are already in a tag

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
...
...
</menu>